# How to export Java OpenGL (JOGL) from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, eclipse-plugin, jogl

I recently built a JOGL Application using Eclipse IDE..
It works perfectly fine when i run it on Eclipse..

However I want to make a .jar file for this application so that I can put it on my website..

Unfortunately when I tried to export it, It says:

JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
- Exported with compile warnings: /BUGS/src/main.java
- Problem writing /BUGS/.DS_Store to JAR: duplicate entry: /DS_Store
- duplicate entry: .DS_Store

I believe this warning wasn't crucial...

but when I actually run the .jar file

It won't run, and says "The Java JAR file "BUGS.jar" could not be launched
Check the Console for possible error messages.

I'm sorry I'm a newb....
How do fix this problem?
How do I check console for possible error messages?

I found a solution in other forum that suggest me to edit the manifest file, but I don't know where to find a manifest file, because I can only see BUG.jar in my directory after i export the application.. It doesn't come with any manifest file or whatsoever.

Or is there any other way to export JOGL?

Thank you....

Cheers...

Comment: It seems that you're trying to re-package an already existent jar, right?

Comment: No. They are all in .java format... So basically I have multiple .java classes.. and I wanted to make it into 1 single .jar file so that i put it on my web...

thanks

Comment: Did you "Check the Console for possible error messages."?  As far as the manifest goes, it's inside the JAR, which is really just a zip file.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do i check the console?

Comment: Tools > Java Console (or Sun Java Console)

Answer (score 2):

I've got a tutorial for this at http://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/tutorial-creating-native-binary-executables-for-multi-platform-java-apps-with-opengl-and-eclipse-rcp/. It shows how to export a JOGL app from Eclipse as a set of native binaries that you can redistribute just like any other program (no Java installation is required on the user's machine).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that problem with .DS_Store before. Try refreshing the project/package. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a "runnable jar" within the Eclipse IDE.All the necessary library files will be packed but there are another set of files called Native files(thos .dll files that u install during JOGL setup) which wont work well even if u add it inside the jar.